# Integrate rational function

Tags: integration

Can you help me to integrate: $$ \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\frac{(1-\cos(x))}{\sin^2(x)}\,dx$$

I've seen Wolfram's solution but was wondering if there was another way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: split the fraction, the integrals become standard

Answer (score 1):

HINT: we have $$\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)^2}=\frac{1-\cos(x)}{1-\cos^2(x)}$$

Answer (score 0):

From $\sin^2 x = 1- \cos^2 x$, we have $\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin^2 x} = \frac{1}{1+\cos x}$.

Now we have to calculate $$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{1+\cos x} dx$$

Use the well-known substitution of $x=2\tan^{-1} z$.

We have $$\cos x = \frac{1-z^2}{1+z^2}$$ $$dx=\frac{2 dz}{1+z^2}$$
Plugging this in, we have $$\int_{\sqrt{2}-1}^{1} 1 dz = 2-\sqrt{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$I = \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin^2 x}dx =\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left[\csc^2 x-\csc x\cdot \cot x\right]dx $$

So we get $$I = -\left[\cot x\right]_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+\left[\csc x\right]_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} = -\left(0-1\right)+\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)=2-\sqrt{2}.$$